# How to graphically represent click data

Tags: interface-design, information-design, representation, data-visualisation

I have a data which contains the number times users **visits** a page and the **time of day** the visit occurs. I would like to display this data visually but I don't know what is the best representation of the data.

I am thinking perhaps a **pie chart** where each slice represents the amount of times a link is clicked. Another option is to display the data as a **bar chart** where each bar height is dependent on the number of times a link is clicked.

Are there other options that I am not aware of, possibly including the time the link was clicked?

Comment: You mention three different elements (number of visits, time of visit and link), but a pie would only display 2 of them (for example, link and amount, not time), and the same for a bar (amount, time, no links). Do you want to display the three?

Comment: Dead on there @Yisela - what is needed is either two representations or a multivariable chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on the actual use; who uses it to what aim. There are a million alternatives, and what you must bear in mind is what data is ok to be *approximately right* and what parts need to be *exactly right*. You could call this the *granularity of the data*.

How the data is fed is of course also a consideration. But mainly: **what** needs to be **how** detailed to **whom** at what **point**? how many levels "down" do you need to accomodate?

The bigger part of your question is extremely complex; it is about visualising data. Being a little practical, I would suggest take a look at **[Google Charts I](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)** and [**Google charts II**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/more_charts) and get some inspiration. You can also get far more elaborate and complex ones, for example **[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).**

---

**EDIT**

BTW: Finally, I have a reason to name [**Sparklines**](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)! They are the best: they are tiny  inline, live charts. They can convey a massive amount of information in ordinary text height. Can you tel I am a big fan? Here is how the defaults look:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first chart type I thought of was a bubble chart.

You could put time as the x-axis and the page link as y-axis and then use the bubbles to represent the number of clicks at that time.

Here is an example of said chart type:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhdHh.jpg]
[Source (raphaeljs)](http://g.raphaeljs.com/dotchart.html) (Thanks [user568458](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26758/how-to-graphically-represent-click-data/26763?noredirect=1#comment34737_26763))

Comment: In my answer I believe I specified that the y-axis should be the link. The example I linked is just an image of a bubble chart. I will update my linked example with yours as it much better represents my idea.

Comment: Yeah, raphael has some nice charts too.